# IEnumSTATURL::Next failing with E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF) errors

Tags: internet-explorer, api, com

Calling [IEnumSTATURL::Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774958.aspx) within my application returns E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF) instead of `S_OK`.  Sadly, that particular error code is the, "I don't know what is wrong" error code, so I am not sure how to fix it.

This also occurs when running [The Tiny Wrapper Class For URL History](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ponta.aspx?msg=3487726).  This only happens on some computers I have tested with.  One of the machines I tested on has IE7 and had this error, other machines with IE7 worked properly.  The machines with this error still have IE history working properly within IE.

One of the machines with this issue used to run the application properly and later stopped working with the same application, so I am confident the issue is at least partially related to the machine's configuration.

I've been doing the coding via C#, but I don't think this issue is a C#-specific issue.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Alternatively, is there a different way to read Internet Explorer's history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry` in wininet.dll.  It seems to do what I want using code like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/62f12225-e06c-4e59-a0aa-2f565a922c71).

It takes me a couple hours of debugging a problem like this, yet once I've posted it on SO I end up thinking of better avenues of research that find solutions much faster.  Ah well, thanks for functioning as a bobble head :/